# Ramp University is set to close OVER THE NEXT YEAR (meaning)

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have to clarify the meaning of the bold letters:

> Ramp University is set to close **OVER THE NEXT YEAR**

Does it mean:

- a) The university will close next year, *throughout* (from Jan. to Dec.)
- b) The university will close next year, but it will close *randomly* (any month)

**Disclaimer**: This is not true, just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both scenarios are possible.

Most likely it indicates the university will be "run down". Parts that can be closed easily get closed first. Classes get reduced to a minimum with no new students joining, and as students finish their course the number of students left reduces until there is no university left.

It doesn't imply that the process will start on January 1st, but it suggests that the process will take a substantial portion of the year.

It could also refer to the school year (September-August), or the financial year (April-March), or the year starting from now.

Comment: Let's make it a total closure. So, when I say ''over the next year'' now, does it imply that the closure next year is still unspecified? Or will it start immediately from January?

Comment: @JohnArvin *Over the next year* means the closure is spread out over a significant portion of the year. The process might start in January but it might not until months later. It may end in September or go until the stroke of midnight on December 31. You would use this wording to be deliberately ambiguous/flexible within a time frame; perhaps the endowment will be dissolved over the next three years but the libraries will be closed over the spring quarter.